# Stacking multiple sticky footers

Tags: javascript, css, footer, sticky, sticky-footer

I'm trying to create multiple sticky footers that stack once you scroll to the bottom of the page: so the bottom footer comes up first and sticks, then another comes up and sits above that, then another comes up and sits above that, etc.
I've used some Javascript to create my first sticky footer, that I found online and edited for my needs:

```
<!-- footer_1 -->
<div>
<img id="footer_1" src="IMAGES/footer_1.png">
</div>

<script>

var footer_1      = document.getElementById("footer_1"),

stop      = footer_1.offsetTop - 400,
docBody   = document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || 
document.body,
hasOffset = window.pageYOffset !== undefined,
scrollTop;

window.onscroll = function (e) {
scrollTop = hasOffset ? window.pageYOffset : docBody.scrollTop;

if (scrollTop >= stop) {
footer_1.className = 'stick';
} else {
footer_1.className = ''; 
 }
}

</script>
```

and my CSS:

```
/* footer_1 */

#footer_1 {
width:100%;
margin:1500px 0 0;

z-index: 950;
}

#footer_1.stick {
position:fixed;
top:0; right:0;
width: 100%;
margin:400px 0 0;


z-index: 950;
}
```

When I try to duplicate this code and create the second footer (changing footer_1 across the Javascript and CSS to footer_2, and changing the margins so that it arrives higher on the page) it throws off the first footer I created, and stops it from sticking.

I'm very new to coding and barely knew how to set this up to begin with! So if there is an easier way for me to create what I need than what I have done already then I am MORE than welcome to suggestions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're using the onscroll event already. Using javascript, check to see if the 2nd footer is visible, and if so, change it's position from relative to fixed (with appropriate bottom px settings).

Comment: @Tyzoid the second footer is visible and it's position is set to fixed, however it still stops the first footer from sticking!

Comment: Can you post a link to jsfiddle demonstrating the issue?